# How to load data into Google Cloud Bigtable from Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-bigtable

I need to populate data into Google Cloud Bigtable and the source of the data will be Google BigQuery.

As an exercise, I am able to [read the data from BigQuery](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/examples/cookbook/BigQueryTornadoes.java) and as an seperate exercise I am able to [write data into Bigtable as well](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=cloud-bigtable-examples-master/java/dataflow-connector-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigtable/dataflow/example/SourceRowCount.java).

Now I have to combine these 2 operations into one Google Cloud Dataflow job. Any example will be of great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the transforms as shown in those examples, adding whatever logic you need in between, for example:

```java
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
 .apply(BigQueryIO.Read.from("some_table"))
 .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<TableRow, Row>() {
   public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
     Row output = somehowConvertYourDataToARow(c.element());
     c.output(output);
   }
   })
 .apply(BigtableIO.Write.withTableId("some_other_table");
```

Comment: I tried executing the following code <code>   CloudBigtableIO.initializeForWrite(p);
   p.apply(BigQueryIO.Read.fromQuery(getQuery()))
   .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<TableRow, Mutation>() {
      public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
        Mutation output = convertDataToRow(c.element());
        c.output(output);
      }

      }))
    .apply(CloudBigtableIO.writeToTable(config));   </code>

Comment: But I got the following Exception                                                                                 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to encode element 'null' with coder 'HBaseMutationCoder'.

Comment: Looks like somewhere in your code you are producing null values, which the Bigtable writer does not accept.  Try logging the mutation to see if it, or a component of it, is null, and make sure that your convertDataToRow function can't produce nulls

Comment: As a separate thing when I am executing a BigQuery query using dataflow job which contains Record type columns(Flatten out) then the TableRow object is not returning the Record type columns but other columns are getting returned. Not sure what could be the reason

Comment: Can you ask that as a separate question, and provide additional information about your query and the results you get?

Comment: done Please check the details @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39047686/tablerow-object-not-returning-record-type-columns-in-dataflow-job

Answer (score 0):

For a people who want to transform bigquery data to bigtable in future can refer to following link

Ref : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/blob/master/java/dataflow-connector-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigtable/dataflow/example/BigQueryBigtableTransfer.java

Comment: can u give an example that uses some sample data? for example, `someID` as rowkey and `name,age` as values? Example - `1, john doe, 30`