# TableRow object not returning Record type columns in dataFlow Job

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

When I am executing BigQuery query using DataFlow job then the TableRow Object which I am getting, as a result, is not returning those columns which are a record type column (Flatten out)

Java Code:

```
p.apply(BigQueryIO.Read.fromQuery(getQuery()))
```

Query:

SELECT BASM.*,BAS.* FROM 
         (Select user_ids.rmId AID, id, user_ids.regis, segment_id from(FLATTEN( [data.base_audience_segment_map20160817], user_ids.rmId)) ) BASM 
         join
         (Select category, sub_category, type, name, segment_id, last_compute_day, description from  [data.base_audience_segments]) BAS 
         on 
         BASM.segment_id=BAS. segment_id order by BASM.AID,BASM.id limit 100

If you see in the above query user_ids.rmId is a Repeatable record type column.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the default behaviour is if your query is returning null values for a column than that column will not be visible under TableRow object

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `BigQueryIO` [without result flattening](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/BigQueryIO.Read.Bound.html#withoutResultFlattening--).

```java
p.apply(BigQueryIO.Read
    .fromQuery(getQuery())
    .withoutResultFlattening())
```