# Unable to encode element with HBaseMutationCoder

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm trying to apply mutations (Increments) to Bigtable via Dataflow using cloud-bigtable-client (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client).

Here is a high-level summary of what my job does:

```
  PCollection<SomeData> somedata = ...;
  somedata.apply(ParDo.of(new CreateMutations()))
      .setCoder(new HBaseMutationCoder()).apply(CloudBigtableIO.writeToTable(config));
  // I don't think it is necessary to explicitly set Coder here; I tried both ways.
```

`CreateMutations` is a DoFn that looks like:

```
// c.element() is KV<String, Iterable<SomeData>>
public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
  Increment mutation = new Increment(c.element().getKey().getBytes());
  for (SomeData data : c.element().getValue()) {
    // Obtain cf (String), qual (String), value (long) from data.
    // None of them is null. 
    mutation.addColumn(cf.getBytes(), qual.getBytes(), value);
  }
  c.output(mutation);
}
```

Surprisingly, the job fails when this DoFn is executed because elements cannot be encoded by HBaseMutationCoder. Here is a small portion of the stack trace:

```
(e8a8d266ed05e19f): java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to encode element 'row=some_string, families={(family=a, columns={some_string/a:2:text/LATEST_TIMESTAMP/Put/vlen=8/seqid=0+=1, some_string/a:8:text/LATEST_TIMESTAMP/Put/vlen=8/seqid=0+=9620}), (family=m, columns={some_string/m:2:text/LATEST_TIMESTAMP/Put/vlen=8/seqid=0+=1, some_string/m:8:text/LATEST_TIMESTAMP/Put/vlen=8/seqid=0+=9620}}' with coder 'HBaseMutationCoder'.
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:160)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunnerBase.java:288)
    at  ......
```

Notice that within the error message, it clearly shows that `row`, `family`,`column` qualifiers, and `value`s are filled properly. This particular error message shows that it contains four cells to be incremented. 
I haven't had trouble using Delete's and Put's, but it's my first time to use Increment's -- is there anything else I need to populate other than row, family, qualifier, and value?

Any help will be really appreciated.

I also tried to use `Put` instead of `Increment` and it worked (it's the same code as above, except for two lines as marked with (*)).

```
// c.element() is KV<String, Iterable<SomeData>>
public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
  Put mutation = new Put(c.element().getKey().getBytes()); //(*)
  for (SomeData data : c.element().getValue()) {
    // Obtain cf (String), qual (String), value (long) from data.
    // None of them is null. 
    mutation.addImmutable(cf.getBytes(), qual.getBytes(), Bytes.toBytes(value)); //(*)
  }
  c.output(mutation);
}
```

(I found a relevant question here: [How to load data into Google Cloud Bigtable from Google BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39044341/how-to-load-data-into-google-cloud-bigtable-from-google-bigquery)
but the issue I am having doesn't seem to be caused by `null` values as all of row/column family/qualifier/value's are filled properly.)

---

update: here's full stack trace I got.

```
    (875583981e325b46): java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to encode element 'row=some_string, families={(family=a, columns={some_string/a:8:some_text/LATEST_TIMESTAMP/Put/vlen=8/seqid=0+=940, some_string/a:2:some_text/LATEST_TIMESTAMP/Put/vlen=8/seqid=0+=2}), (family=m, columns={some_string/m:2:some_text/LATEST_TIMESTAMP/Put/vlen=8/seqid=0+=2, some_string/m:8:some_text/LATEST_TIMESTAMP/Put/vlen=8/seqid=0+=940}}' with coder 'HBaseMutationCoder'.
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:160)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunnerBase.java:288)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunnerBase.java:284)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnProcessContext$1.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunnerBase.java:508)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.GroupAlsoByWindowsViaIteratorsDoFn.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowsViaIteratorsDoFn.java:123)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:49)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase.processElement(DoFnRunnerBase.java:139)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:188)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ForwardingParDoFn.processElement(ForwardingParDoFn.java:42)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.processElement(DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.java:47)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:55)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:221)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:182)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:69)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.executeWork(DataflowWorker.java:284)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.doWork(DataflowWorker.java:220)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(DataflowWorker.java:170)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:192)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:172)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:159)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to encode element 'row=some_string, families={(family=a, columns={some_string/a:8:some_text/LATEST_TIMESTAMP/Put/vlen=8/seqid=0+=940, some_string/a:2:some_text/LATEST_TIMESTAMP/Put/vlen=8/seqid=0+=2}), (family=m, columns={some_string/m:2:some_text/LATEST_TIMESTAMP/Put/vlen=8/seqid=0+=2, some_string/m:8:some_text/LATEST_TIMESTAMP/Put/vlen=8/seqid=0+=940}}' with coder 'HBaseMutationCoder'.
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:35)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrapIf(UserCodeException.java:40)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase.wrapUserCodeException(DoFnRunnerBase.java:369)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:51)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase.processElement(DoFnRunnerBase.java:139)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:188)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ForwardingParDoFn.processElement(ForwardingParDoFn.java:42)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.processElement(DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.java:47)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:55)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:158)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to encode element 'row=some_string, families={(family=a, columns={some_string/a:8:some_text/LATEST_TIMESTAMP/Put/vlen=8/seqid=0+=940, some_string/a:2:some_text/LATEST_TIMESTAMP/Put/vlen=8/seqid=0+=2}), (family=m, columns={some_string/m:2:some_text/LATEST_TIMESTAMP/Put/vlen=8/seqid=0+=2, some_string/m:8:some_text/LATEST_TIMESTAMP/Put/vlen=8/seqid=0+=940}}' with coder 'HBaseMutationCoder'.
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:160)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunnerBase.java:288)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnProcessContext.output(DoFnRunnerBase.java:450)
    at com.moloco.dataflow.bigtable.AptRecovery$UpdateCountPerCell.processElement(AptRecovery.java:78)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to encode element 'row=some_string, families={(family=a, columns={some_string/a:8:some_text/LATEST_TIMESTAMP/Put/vlen=8/seqid=0+=940, some_string/a:2:some_text/LATEST_TIMESTAMP/Put/vlen=8/seqid=0+=2}), (family=m, columns={some_string/m:2:some_text/LATEST_TIMESTAMP/Put/vlen=8/seqid=0+=2, some_string/m:8:some_text/LATEST_TIMESTAMP/Put/vlen=8/seqid=0+=940}}' with coder 'HBaseMutationCoder'.
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.StandardCoder.getEncodedElementByteSize(StandardCoder.java:170)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.StandardCoder.registerByteSizeObserver(StandardCoder.java:185)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.WindowedValue$FullWindowedValueCoder.registerByteSizeObserver(WindowedValue.java:641)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.WindowedValue$FullWindowedValueCoder.registerByteSizeObserver(WindowedValue.java:552)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.MapTaskExecutorFactory$ElementByteSizeObservableCoder.registerByteSizeObserver(MapTaskExecutorFactory.java:351)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputObjectAndByteCounter.update(OutputObjectAndByteCounter.java:125)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowOutputCounter.update(DataflowOutputCounter.java:61)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:46)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:158)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunnerBase.java:288)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnProcessContext.output(DoFnRunnerBase.java:450)
    at com.moloco.dataflow.bigtable.AptRecovery$UpdateCountPerCell.processElement(AptRecovery.java:78)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:49)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase.processElement(DoFnRunnerBase.java:139)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:188)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ForwardingParDoFn.processElement(ForwardingParDoFn.java:42)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.processElement(DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.java:47)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:55)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:158)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunnerBase.java:288)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunnerBase.java:284)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnProcessContext$1.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunnerBase.java:508)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.GroupAlsoByWindowsViaIteratorsDoFn.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowsViaIteratorsDoFn.java:123)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:49)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase.processElement(DoFnRunnerBase.java:139)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:188)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ForwardingParDoFn.processElement(ForwardingParDoFn.java:42)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.processElement(DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.java:47)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:55)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:221)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:182)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:69)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.executeW
```

Comment: Do you see a "Caused by:.. " in the stack trace? Can you share it? This may narrow down what's going on here.

Comment: Let me update the question with a full stack trace -- I wasn't sure

Answer (score 1):

OK, I see an IllegalArgumentException thrown by HBaseMutationCoder.java. Looking at https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/hbase/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/hbase/HBaseMutationCoder.java#L68 , INCREMENT does not work because it's not idempotent (but PUT is), which explains what you're seeing.